# Cakephp 3 input auto label

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, user-input

I have a code in my indext.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name'); ?>
```

It gives me
[image]

Label is named `Full Name` my target is `Full name`

I know i can use:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name', ['label'=>'Full name']); ?>
```

My question is: Can i do it globaly? Somehow override `ucwords();` using in auto generating labels to `ucfirst();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cakephp generate the label text (when not provided) [here](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#796-866)

It uses `Inflector::Humanize()` (see the [manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html))

I guess you can override the default helper (remember that `input()` is deprecated and you should use `control()` instead)

```
class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper
{

    public function control($fieldName, array $options = [])
    {
        if(!isset($options['label']))
            $options['label'] = // you own code here;
        return parent::control($fieldName, $options);
    }
}
```

then in your `AppView.php` `initialize()` you load your helper

```
$this->loadHelper('Form', [
    'className' => 'MyForm',
]);
```

So when you want to define a custom label you use the `'label'` option

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name', ['label'=>'Insert the full name here']); ?>
```

Instead if you don't set the `'label'` option

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name'); ?>
```

the helper will use your logic

I tested the behavior and it works in my forms

Comment: You need the `!` because when you explicitly se the `'label'` option you don't want the helper to create it automatically

Comment: I'm missing something. I want to override it. But with `!` if `label` was generated automatically there is no override. Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes i see your point, thanks. It only auto generates if nothing was set. In other words if there is no `!` I will always override a label. Thanks again.